Issues with step_interact in a recipe in R
trying to fit a model but keep getting this error about step_interact. No idea what the issue is.
code:
    recipe1 <- recipe(survived~pclass+sex+age+sib_sp+parch+fare,data=training) 
    %>% step_impute_linear(age)               %>%        step_dummy(all_nominal()) 
    %>% step_interact(~sex:fare+age:fare)
    recipe1
    log1 <- logistic_reg() %>% set_engine("glm") %>% set_mode("classification")
    workflow1 <- workflow() %>% add_model(log1) %>% add_recipe(recipe1)
    fit1 <- fit(workflow1,data=training)

error:
Error in step_interact():
Caused by error in rlang::f_rhs():
! x must be a formula
Backtrace:

generics::fit(workflow1, data = training)
rlang::abort(message = message)
Error in step_interact() :
Caused by error in rlang::f_rhs():
! x must be a formula
[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/v8lQWzMo.png)

Tried tweaking the step_interact but nothing worked unless I completely removed it. I need to include interactions in my model.

Welcome to SO! It would be easier to help you if you provide a minimal reproducible example including a minimal but complete and runnable code and a snippet of your input data shared using dput() (or using some fake data or using a built-in dataset).

@Ovr: did you read the documentation about the function via ?step_interact? Have a look at the arguments of this function, especially the "terms" argument. The examples might also point you towards potential problems.

Assuming that some of sex, age, and fare are factors, you need to specify their interactions using dplyr selectors (such as starts_with()). Using step_dummy() means that the original columns are not there in subsequent steps (as is documented in the help file).
